# Wordpress custom post upload post_parent is 0

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, upload

I'm using wordpress custom file uploader of custom post type but my uploaded image is not exists post_parent;

after my uploaded I'm showing phpmyadmin and my uploaded file post_parent 0

What can I do solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with change thickbox parameter

```
<input type="button" class="tosf-upload-button" value="Upload Image" onclick="tb_show('','media-upload.php?post_id=<?php echo $post->ID;?>&type=image&TB_iframe=1&width=753&height=242');" />
```